# JavaScript logic fail

Tags: javascript, logic

I've written a script adapted from another site but the logic is failing:

```
            // read users file
            // from: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/parsing-a-csv-file-with-javascript--cms-25626
            $.ajax({
                url: 'users.csv',
                dataType: 'text',
            }).done(compareCredentials);
        }

        // function to read csv file data adapted from:
        // https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/parsing-a-csv-file-with-javascript--cms-25626
        function compareCredentials(data){
            var allRows=data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
            console.log(allRows);
            var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
            var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
            var success=false;

            // skip row zero as it's the header row
            for (var oneRow=1; oneRow < allRows.length ; oneRow++) {
                var rowCells=allRows[oneRow].split(',');
                if (rowCells[0].value===username);{
                    if (rowCells[1].value===password);{
                        document.getElementById("loginForm").style.display="none";
                        msg="Username: " + username + "  Password: " + password;
                        console.log(msg);
                        msg="File Username: " + rowCells[0] + " File Password: " + rowCells[1];
                        console.log(msg)
                        success=true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The conditions are being met even when not true as evidenced in the Console.

Furthermore I tried:

```
if (rowCells[0]==username && rowCells[1]=password);{}
```

and this didn't make a difference either (which is why I then broke them down into separate logic steps).

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: “What am I doing wrong?” – Adapting scripts from another site. Write your own code, and code you understand. Start by reading documentations.

Comment: I do hope that you are aware that if this code is executed on the user's browser, it can be easily circumvented.

Comment: @BertrandMarron - Thanks Bertrand but it's not for anything 'functional' per se.

Comment: @Ivar - Yes, I know. The code is for a school exercise where a login form is validated. However, whilst it can be done using 'hard code' I'd prefer, however weak, to at least validate it from a file.

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed it. Extra semi-colons in the IF statement (before the parentheses). Haven't worked out yet how ! works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be in:

```
if (rowCells[0].value===username);{
```

which should have read:

```
if (rowCells[0]===username){

Appreciate the help guys.
```